# Appropriate way of quoting

Tags: syntactic-analysis, quotations

When you are quoting someone's assertion, this happens the following way:

> God answered, "The sun is not appropriated to catch up the moon, nor can night outstrip the day."

Notice the comma, followed by the quotation marks. Now take this example into account:

> I am quoting you: "This verse is beyond a shadow of doubt representing geocentrism."
>
> Another assertion of yours: “Your analogy of Copernican heliocentrism is abstract

Notice how I put a colon. I think it is more appropriate in this snippet. Am I doing this right?

Comment: It strikes me as a style choice. Perhaps if you were quoting a conversation and had to identify speakers over and over, set in paragraphs like prose, the comma would be less distracting than the colon.

Comment: Thank you. After a bit of research I found this: "Use commas to introduce quotations that consist of less than seven words and colons to introduce anything longer than that."

Comment: Where does that advice appear? (Your first quote violates that rule, by the way.)

Comment: I found this here: https://www.vappingo.com/word-blog/colon-or-comma-before-quotation-marks/

Comment: I am aware of this, 7 words might refer to a small sentence, as mine is. However, example sentences on the website make me doubt this.

Comment: Both are acceptable. No-one will have reasonable grounds for complaint if you stick with commas. Supposed "rules" as in the website you show are nothing more than matters of style. And even that website says, "it doesn’t really matter".

Comment: I think you need commas around the parenthetical clause "beyond a shadow of a doubt" (otherwise it reads a little as though the geocentrism is beyond doubt, rather than what the verse is about).